# yii, pass vars from controller to another controller and so on

Tags: php, yii, controller

im trying to pass a var that comes from a controller to another controller, so this controller will render a view that will renderpartial another view, i will give the code.

controller 1:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $pet=new Peticion;
    $this->performAjaxValidation($pet);
    if(isset($_POST['Peticion']))
    {

        $pet->attributes=$_POST['Peticion'];

        if($pet->save())
            $this->redirect(array('parametro/create', 'pest'=>$pet->id));

    }

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id), 'pet'=>$pet
    ));
}
```

Controller 2:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Parametro;

        $variable = file_get_contents('protected\column.txt');
        $vars = explode(' ', $variable);
      // make SURE that you are getting $vars as array
      if(isset($_POST['Parametro']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Parametro'];
            if(isset($_POST['createCheck']))
        {
             $newVar=array();
            $checkVariables=$_POST['createCheck'];
            foreach($checkVariables as $key)
            {
                $newVar[]=$vars[$key];
            }
            if(!empty($newVar))
            {
                foreach($newVar as $saveIt)
                {

                $model->$saveIt=1;
                }
                $model->save();

                echo 'saved';
            }    

           }
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        if(isset($pest))
            throw new CHttpException('var exists');

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'variable'=>$vars,
        ));
    }
```

im trying to pass the var $pest, im making a throw CHttp message to see if the var is being passed, but its no, does anyone see if im doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
$this->redirect(array('parametro/create', 'pest'=>$pet->id));
```

You are trying to pass the **pest** argument to the actionCreate but you haven't declared pest as a parameter in the action create. SO you need to do this

```
public function actionCreate($pest)
{
// you can use $pest now
// your code
}
```

**NOTE:-** Now if you will try to call this actionCreate **without passing the $pest parameter** then it will throw exception.